# Jenkins - How to run job only if another job failed for n-times

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

i want to trigger/start a job (jobB) only if another job (jobA) failed for n-times after the last success.
i saw this [parameterized trigger plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-trigger/) - but for triggers you only can say "Failed" but you can't define whether it should trigger after a failed counter.

Thanks
Chris

Comment: I presume you mean failed n-times in a row? Write a groovy script to check lastBuild - lastSuccessfulBuild >= n, then trigger jobB

Comment: thanks for your input. Using a groovy script works

Answer (score 0):

here my groovy script thats solved the issue. Used g[roovy-postbuild plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/groovy-postbuild/) to exec the script on jobA. Thanks Ian W for your input.

```
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

job_name = "jobA"
job_name_to_run = "jobB"
triggerThreshold = 2
last_succ_num = 0
last_job_num = 0
def currentBuild = Thread.currentThread().executable
def job = Hudson.instance.getJob(job_name)
def job_data = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(job.fullName)
println 'Job: ' + job_data.fullName
if (job_data.getLastBuild()) {
   last_job_num = job_data.getLastBuild().getNumber()
}
println 'last_job_num: ' + last_job_num
if (job_data.getLastSuccessfulBuild()) {
   last_succ_num = job_data.getLastSuccessfulBuild().getNumber()
}
println 'last_succ_num: ' + last_succ_num
doRunJob =(last_job_num - last_succ_num >= triggerThreshold)
println 'do run job? ' + doRunJob
if (doRunJob){
  def jobToRun = Hudson.instance.getJob(job_name_to_run)
  def cause = new Cause.UpstreamCause(currentBuild)
  def causeAction = new hudson.model.CauseAction(cause) 
  Hudson.instance.queue.schedule(jobToRun, 0, causeAction)
}
```